# A Conformal map sends the upper semi-circle to the positive real line and $[-1,1]$ to the other half of the real line.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

> Is there a conformal mapping that sends the upper semi-circle to the positive (or negative) real line, and the real interval $[-1,1]$ to the other half of the real line?

I am considering the upper semi-circle $\{|z|=1, 0<arg(z)<\pi\}$, with the line $[-1,1]$ that closes the loop.

I want to map the arc to a half line, and the interval to the other half line.

Is this possible?

I have tried for a bit, with no success so far.

The end goal is to find a harmonic function on this upper semi-disk, but I think the conformal mapping needs to be executed first...

I used the Joukowski transform, since part of the problem statement specifically asks to compute its image, but this transform takes the arc to an interval $[-2,2]$, which is not at all helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not so hard. First use a fractional-linear that takes $1\mapsto0$, $-1\mapsto\infty$, $0\mapsto i$, and $i\mapsto1$. You get this by $$z\mapsto-i\frac{z-1}{z+1}\,.$$
You see that this therefore takes your semicircular arc to the positive real axis and the line segment $[-1,1]$ to the positive imaginary axis. Now square the result. Your mapping is $$z\mapsto-\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2\,.$$

Comment: Hi Professor Lubin, I had arrived at the first mapping but didn't know what to do with it.  I was confused as to whether the image of [-1,1] was all of the imaginary axis or just the positive imaginary axis.  I am aware that knowing where 3 distinct points maps to determines the entire linear transformation, but somehow the infinity confused me a bit, and made me think that perhaps the image comes back around to achieve the negative imaginary axis also.  I am guessing this is incorrect.  And also, thanks so much for suggesting to square the mapping.  Have a great night @Lubin :-)

Comment: To tell the truth, I substituted a few values on the boundary and inside the semicircular region to check that all was as it should be. Never underestimate the utility of hand computation!

Comment: Hi Professor Lubin, thanks for your additional comment -- I absolutely love traditional hand computation, doing mathematics on pen and paper.  I love the classical training and am sort of not looking forward to the day when I have to start doing lots and lots of computer programming, but perhaps that day won't be so bad :-).

Comment: I thought just a bit more about why the image perhaps couldn't possibly come back around to achieve the negative imaginary axis:  if the whole of the imaginary axis is achieved, plus the positive real axis, then this creates an impossible situation for the image of the interior of the upper semi-disk.  The interior is a connected set, and so it must map to a connected set, and hence it must land in quadrant I, as the mapping is continuous away from z = -1.  Thanks again and I hope to hear from you soon.  Have a great night, @Lubin :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$
$$f(x)=\frac{i-x}{i+x}.$$
This (invertible) map takes the (extended) real line to the unit circle. This can obviously be restricted to the upper half circle, which maps to the negative $x-$axis. There are many ways to map $[-1,1]$ to the (extended) positive $x-$axis, $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2}$ for example.

Comment: Hi @charlestoncrabb, the inverse mapping would map the circle back to the real line, but this only helps with mapping the arc to a half line.  The hard part is mapping the interval [-1,1] that closes the upper semi-disk to the other half of the real line in the w-plane.  I don't see that this mapping achieves this goal.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have edited accordingly